# PROLOG Make a list of words from big text file

Tags: prolog, file-handling, gnu-prolog

I'm new in Prolog.
I have a dictionary of 660000 lines (so a text file), where every word is in a different line, like this:

```
hello
everyone
thanks
for
help
```

I have to put these words into a list because I have to verify if user's input word is in this text file.
So I should have something like this:

```
[hello, everyone, thanks, for, help]
```

I tried many solutions, but due to the huge number of words (I think), the program returns *Fatal Error: global stack overflow*.
If the following can be a solution, is there a way to read a block of words from the file and if the user's word is not in this block, clear the stack and read another block of words till the end of file to avoid stack overflow error?
**I'm using GNU-Prolog**, not SWI-Prolog, so I can't use predicates like *read_line_to_string/2*.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should show at least one solution that demonstrates the stack overflow. Do you now what exactly causes it? It could be the list, it could be something about the way you read, maybe you have an error? Have you tried implementing your own "read line"? It cannot be too difficult....

Comment: See http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/gprolog008.html for giving gprolog more memory.

Comment: Logtalk supports GNU Prolog and provides a `reader` library (https://logtalk.org/manuals/libraries/reader.html) with similar predicates.

Comment: "so I can't use predicates like read_line_to_string/2." of course you can. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you load the list of words from the file, how are you going to use it? Could it be easier to add the words as a table of facts? So, if your file is:

```
this
is
a
file
```

then you have a table of facts and you can query:

```
| ?- word(X).

X = this ? ;

X = (is) ? ;

X = a ? ;

X = file

(1 ms) yes
```

This might resolve your memory problem, too. Who knows....

But you still need to figure out how to read a line from input. [On SWI-Prolog's website](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/readutil.pl?show=src#read_line_to_codes/2) you see an implementation of "read line to codes"; **why won't you use it?** I copied it, compiled it, and it just works:

```
pl_read_line_to_codes(Stream, Codes) :-
    get_code(Stream, C0),
    (   C0 == -1
    ->  Codes0 = end_of_file
    ;   read_1line_to_codes(C0, Stream, Codes0)
    ),
    Codes = Codes0.

read_1line_to_codes(-1, _, []) :- !.
read_1line_to_codes(10, _, []) :- !.
read_1line_to_codes(13, Stream, L) :-
    !,
    get_code(Stream, C2),
    read_1line_to_codes(C2, Stream, L).
read_1line_to_codes(C, Stream, [C|T]) :-
    get_code(Stream, C2),
    read_1line_to_codes(C2, Stream, T).
```

Here is how I read the first line to an atom:

```
| ?- open(foo, read, In),
     pl_read_line_to_codes(In, Line),
     close(In),
     atom_codes(A, Line).

A = this
In = '$stream'(3)
Line = [116,104,105,115]

(1 ms) yes
```

Now, if you take [the example code under the docs for read_line_to_codes/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_line_to_codes/2), where it says "Backtrack over lines in a file", and just use that, replacing `read_line_to_codes/2` with your definition of `pl_read_line_to_codes/2`:

```
stream_line(In, Line) :-
    repeat,
    (   pl_read_line_to_string(In, Line0),
        Line0 \== end_of_file
    ->  atom_codes(Line, Line0)
    ;   !,
        fail
    ).
```

it already works:

```
| ?- open(foo, read, In),
     \+ ( stream_line(In, W),
          \+ assertz(myword(W))
        ),
     close(In).

In = '$stream'(4)

yes
| ?- myword(X).

X = this ? ;

X = (is) ? ;

X = a ? ;

X = file

(1 ms) yes
```

Does it work for 660000 words? You should try it out. When I tried with ~700K words, GNU-Prolog complained that:

```
Fatal Error: Atom table full (max atom: 32768, environment variable used: MAX_ATOM)
```

I fixed this by starting GNU-Prolog like this:

```
$ MAX_ATOM=999999 gprolog
```

Reading all ~700K words takes about 2.5 minutes on my computer, so pretty slow.